# Drawing a random sample from a numpy array with index

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy matrix of size 12x12 containing probabilities. The aim is to take a random sample using these probabilities, then return the index of the sample.

At the moment I am using the following code to do this based on `np.random.choice`, where **grid** = the numpy matrix:

```
    rnd_choice = np.random.choice(grid.size, p=grid.ravel() / grid.ravel().sum())
    sample_index = np.unravel_index(rnd_choice, grid.shape)
```

The problem is speed, as I have to do this several thousand times throughout a simulation. Snakeviz highlighted this as an area for improvement, therefore, I was wondering if anyone had any ideas as to how to increase the speed of this?

The Python version used in the code above is Python 3.8.

Comment: The first thing to do would be to calculate `p=grid.ravel() / grid.ravel().sum()` in a variable outside the loop, at least if the grid doesn't get changed. If that is possible, also the random choice could calculate a complete array of choices (with replacement) at once.

Comment: Unfortunately the grid needs to be calculated within each loop, as the probabilities are different each time.

Answer (score 2):

The following seems a bit (x4 on my laptop) faster:

```
c = grid.ravel().cumsum()                                              
out = np.unravel_index(c.searchsorted(rng.uniform(0,c[-1])),grid.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `grid.ravel` needs to be calculated within the for loop, because the probabilities change during each cycle of the for loop, you can potentially still decrease the computational burden by factor of two, by calling `.ravel()` only once per cycle:

```
for cycle in loop:
    # grid gets renewed here...
    g_ravel = grid.ravel()         # do the ravel() process only once

    rnd_choice = np.random.choice(grid.size, p=g_ravel / g_ravel.sum())
    sample_index = np.unravel_index(rnd_choice, grid.shape)
```